# Lectura de datos de giroscopio y mostrar en interfaz grafica attributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'after'

Tags: python, interfaz-gráfica

Necesito leer los datos de un giroscopio y mostrarlos en una interfaz gráfica, sin embargo me muestra este error:

> attributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'after'

Este es mi código:

```
import smbus
import math
import sys
impor time
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
from Tkinter import *


# Register
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c


def read_byte(reg):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, reg)

def read_word(reg):
    h = bus.read_byte_data(address, reg)
    l = bus.read_byte_data(address, reg+1)
    value = (h << 8) + l
    return value

def read_word_2c(reg):
    val = read_word(reg)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b))

def get_y_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(x, dist(y,z))
    return -math.degrees(radians)

def get_x_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(y, dist(x,z))
    return math.degrees(radians)


def position():


        # Aktivieren, um das Modul ansprechen zu koennen
        bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)
        gyroskop_xout = read_word_2c(0x43)
        gyroskop_yout = read_word_2c(0x45)
        gyroskop_zout = read_word_2c(0x47)
        beschleunigung_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
        beschleunigung_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
        beschleunigung_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)
        beschleunigung_xout_skaliert = beschleunigung_xout / 16384.0
        beschleunigung_yout_skaliert = beschleunigung_yout / 16384.0
        beschleunigung_zout_skaliert = beschleunigung_zout / 16384.0
        print ("X Rotation: " , get_x_rotation(beschleunigung_xout_skaliert, beschleunigung_yout_skaliert, beschleunigung_zout_skaliert))
        print ("Y Rotation: " , get_y_rotation(beschleunigung_xout_skaliert, beschleunigung_yout_skaliert, beschleunigung_zout_skaliert))                         
        dato = (get_x_rotation(beschleunigung_xout_skaliert, beschleunigung_yout_skaliert, beschleunigung_zout_skaliert))
        valor = dato[0:1]
        lectura.set(valor)
        positionX.after(1000, position)


#Interfaz grÃ¡fica
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry ("1000x500+0+0")
ventana.title("Proyecto Final")

TpositionX = Label(ventana, text = "PosiciÃ³n en X: ").place(x=100 , y=70)

lectura = StringVar()

positionX = Label (ventana, textvariable = lectura).place(x = 100 , y= 100)

BSalir = Button(ventana, text = "Salir", command = exit).place(x = 100, y=130)

positionX(1000, position)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un error muy común en Tkinter, tu instancias `positionX` en la siguiente línea:

```
positionX = Label (ventana, textvariable = lectura).place(x = 100 , y= 100)
```

Luego intentas aplicar métodos sobre `positionX` creyendo que es una etiqueta pero esto no es cierto. `positionX` es `None` porque no es el retorno de `Tkinter.Label` sino del método `place` que retorna `None`. Debes separar la instancia de la etiqueta del uso de su método `place` para que el nombre apunte al objeto Label y puedas usarlo posteriormente:

```
positionX = Label (ventana, textvariable = lectura)
positionX.place(x = 100 , y= 100)
```

Aparte de eso dos cosas más:

- Importar usando `from Tkinter import *` es una mala práctica que ha de evitarse. Usa `from Tkinter import Label, Button`, `import Tkinter` o `import Tkinter as tk`.
- Por otro lado, **el uso de `exit` va a bloquear la Gui**, usa el método `quit()` en su lugar. Si usas el IDLE como IDE aparentemente no funciona pero es porque el IDLE usa también Tkinter y tiene su propio mainloop sobre el que corre también tu app. Si pruebas el código en la terminal funcionará como debe.

Tu código debería ser:

```
import smbus
import math
import sys
import time
import numpy as np
import pylab as pl
import Tkinter as tk

#Debes crear la instancia de bus y definir address (modificalo de acuerdo a tu caso)
bus = smbus.SMBus(1)
address = 0x68 #Valor de address

# Register
power_mgmt_1 = 0x6b
power_mgmt_2 = 0x6c


def read_byte(reg):
    return bus.read_byte_data(address, reg)

def read_word(reg):
    h = bus.read_byte_data(address, reg)
    l = bus.read_byte_data(address, reg+1)
    value = (h << 8) + l
    return value

def read_word_2c(reg):
    val = read_word(reg)
    if (val >= 0x8000):
        return -((65535 - val) + 1)
    else:
        return val

def dist(a,b):
    return math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b))

def get_y_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(x, dist(y,z))
    return -math.degrees(radians)

def get_x_rotation(x,y,z):
    radians = math.atan2(y, dist(x,z))
    return math.degrees(radians)

def position():
    # Aktivieren, um das Modul ansprechen zu koennen
    bus.write_byte_data(address, power_mgmt_1, 0)
    gyroskop_xout = read_word_2c(0x43)
    gyroskop_yout = read_word_2c(0x45)
    gyroskop_zout = read_word_2c(0x47)
    beschleunigung_xout = read_word_2c(0x3b)
    beschleunigung_yout = read_word_2c(0x3d)
    beschleunigung_zout = read_word_2c(0x3f)
    beschleunigung_xout_skaliert = beschleunigung_xout / 16384.0
    beschleunigung_yout_skaliert = beschleunigung_yout / 16384.0
    beschleunigung_zout_skaliert = beschleunigung_zout / 16384.0
    print ("X Rotation: " , get_x_rotation(beschleunigung_xout_skaliert, beschleunigung_yout_skaliert, beschleunigung_zout_skaliert))
    print ("Y Rotation: " , get_y_rotation(beschleunigung_xout_skaliert, beschleunigung_yout_skaliert, beschleunigung_zout_skaliert))                         
    dato = (get_x_rotation(beschleunigung_xout_skaliert, beschleunigung_yout_skaliert, beschleunigung_zout_skaliert))
    lectura.set(dato)
    positionX.after(1000, position)

#Interfaz gráfica
ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry ("1000x500+0+0")
ventana.title("Proyecto Final")

TpositionX = tk.Label(ventana, text = "Posicisión en X: ")
TpositionX.place(x=100 , y=70)

lectura = tk.StringVar()

positionX = tk.Label (ventana, textvariable = lectura)
positionX.place(x = 100 , y= 100)

BSalir = tk.Button(ventana, text = "Salir", command = ventana.quit)
BSalir.place(x = 100, y=130)

positionX.after(100, position)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hola FJSevilla muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con tu mejora la ventana ya sale sin embargo nunca se muestra el valor que envía el giroscopio. Me marca este error. NameError: global name 'bus' is not defined,

Comment: Tenia funcionando el código del giroscopio y no tenia ese problema, supongo que sucede al tenerlo en una función. Ya intente declarar bus como global pero sigo teniendo el error.

Comment: @Fatima tal y como dices bus no existe, debes declararlo/instanciar al principio del módulo **antes de definir las funciones**. ¿Como instancias `bus`?, ¿Algo como  `bus = smbus.SMBus(1)`? Como usas métodos de la instancia  no tendrias necesidad de usar `global` en principio. Para estos problemas usar clases (POO) ahorra muchos problemas.

Comment: @Fatima he editado el código de la respuesta para mostrar lo que digo, además de `bus`, tampoco declaras `address`. Para poder ayudarte mejor sería bueno saber como instancias bus, como defines address para ajustarlo a tu caso concreto. Saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias por la observación, la dirección address debe ser 0x68, de hecho ya he editado la publicación. Solo que ahora tengo este error **TypeError: 'float´object has no attribute ' __getitem__' ** , haciendo referencia a la linea de valor = dato[0:1]. Muchas gracias de antemano por tu ayuda.

Comment: @Fatima `dato` es la salida de `get_x_rotation` que retorna la salida de `math.degrees` es decir grados decimales en forma de un float (90.2511 por ejemplo).¿ Que se supone que pretendes hacer con `dato[0:1]`?, no puedes hacer slicing sobre un float.

Comment: He logrado que corra el código, sin embargo tengo un problema y no sé por que sucede ya que no me genera ningún error. Te explico si yo corro el código para solo mostrar la rotación de X los datos en la ventana se actualizan correctamente, sin embargo yo agrego los mismo pasos para mostar también la rotación ene y, es decir visualizar al mismo tiempo X y Y, en la ventana se actulizan unas 6 veces y después se queda pasmada, no me genera ningún error.

Comment: @Fatima posiblemente el problema sea que la función `position` o la que tengas ahora que retorne los valores (lo que llamas con `after`) tarda mucho en responder o directamente se queda esperando datos que no le llegan del bus por alguna razón. Si esto pasa la GUI se bloqueará. Deberías ver si por alguna razón los calculos tardan demasiador, esto es difícil de simular por nosotros porque no tenemos el hardware que tienes tu y podria ser problema de el que no actualiza el bus con nuevos datos.

Comment: Si no das con nada podrias crear una implemntación multihilos para que si la lectura del bus o los calculos son lentos la GUI no se congele. Si no das con la solución crea otra pregunta para no alterar esta más ya que es un problema diferente. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias ya he podido resolver el problema con tu sugerencia y ya no tengo problema con la interfaz, se actualizan los datos correctamente.

Comment: @Fatima en [es.so] no existe forma de hacer comunicaciones privadas entre usuarios ni se alienta a ello ya que va en contra de la filosofía del sitio. Lo que si se puede es hablar por el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) general o crear una sala (también es público pero no se va a encontrar desde una búsqueda externa). Si quieres llamar la atención de alguien en concreto solo usa la '@' antes de su nombre de usuario. Saludos.